# Coinbase API Invalid Signature error when using Create Address PHP curl request

Tags: php, curl, coinbase-api

From the Coinbase API documentation, to create a new address:

```html
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b/addresses \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c' \
  -d '{"name": "New receive address"}'
```

Here's my curl request in PHP:

```
private function api_settings($request_path, $method, $options = [])
{
    $api_url = "https://api.coinbase.com";
    $secret = $this->api_secret;
    $timestamp = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time"), true)["data"]["epoch"];;
    $url = $api_url . $request_path;

    $string = $timestamp . $method . $request_path;
    $sig = hash_hmac("sha256", $string, $secret);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    if ($method == "POST") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($options));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    } elseif($method == "PUT") {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($options));
    }

    $headers = [
        "CB-ACCESS-KEY: $this->api_key",
        "CB-ACCESS-SIGN: $sig",
        "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: $timestamp",
        "CB_VERSION: 2022-03-12",
        "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8"
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Here's how I try to call the `api_settings()`:

```
$api_settings = $this->api_settings('/v2/accounts/' . $this->account_id . '/addresses', 'POST', array('name' => $this->label));
    $result = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($api_settings, true);
```

I do it by passing an array as an optional function parameter for the `POST`.

This always returns `{"errors":[{"id":"authentication_error","message":"invalid signature"}]}` no matter what I do. I've tried using both `json_encode` and `http_build_query` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and it still doesn't work.

What could be wrong here?